# polymorphism with reference member variable

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, pass-by-reference

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my program below? I am using a reference member variable in a class for polymorphism. I am expecting the second cout to say "derived2" but it says "base";

```
#include <iostream>

// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class base
{
public:
    virtual void print(){ std::cout<<"base"<<std::endl;}
};
class derived: public base
{
public:
    virtual void print(){ std::cout<<"derived"<<std::endl;}
};

class derived2: public base
{
    virtual void print(){ std::cout<<"derived2"<<std::endl;}
};

class foo
{
public:
    base & bar;
    base boo;
    derived foobar;
    derived2 foobar2;
    foo(): bar(boo){}
    void newfoo(base & newfoo){ bar = newfoo; bar.print();}
};
int main()
{
  foo test;
  test.bar.print();
  test.newfoo(test.foobar2);
}
```

Output:
    base
    base

Comment: You should know that you almost never want to use references as member variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others, you cannot reassign a reference.
Whenever you do something like `bar = newfoo` you are not resetting the reference. Instead you are invoking `operator=` for `bar` with `newfoo` as an argument.
Therefore, in your case you are *slicing* your objects and (let me say) copying its `base` part in `bar`.

---

A kind of reference-like tool to which you can reassign exists in the standard template library and it's called `std::reference_wrapper`.
It follows an example based on your code that uses it and has the expected behavior:

```
#include<functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class base
{
public:
    virtual void print() { std::cout<<"base"<<std::endl;}
};
class derived: public base
{
public:
    virtual void print(){ std::cout<<"derived"<<std::endl;}
};

class derived2: public base
{
    virtual void print(){ std::cout<<"derived2"<<std::endl;}
};

class foo
{
public:
    std::reference_wrapper<base> bar;
    base boo;
    derived foobar;
    derived2 foobar2;
    foo(): bar(boo){}
    void newfoo(base & newfoo){ bar = newfoo; bar.get().print();}
};
int main()
{
  foo test;
  test.bar.get().print();
  test.newfoo(test.foobar2);
}
```

In this case, `operator=` actually rebinds the reference to the given object. Anyway, as you can see, in this case you must invoke `get` to access the underlying reference.

Note: set aside the example above, your code isn't the typical use case for a `std::reference_wrapper`.
I mentioned it only for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Does references work with polymorphism? The internet makes it sound like a pointer and references work the same as far as polymorphism.

Comment: @sdstack References and pointers are the intended tools to be used when polymorphic types are involved. Otherwise you can incur in slicing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'reassign' the reference. When assignment operator is used with the reference, it assigns the underlying value.

Thus, `bar = newfoo;` simply assigns `foo` of the `base` type to `foobar`, slicing it in the process.

You could have a different behavior if you'd substitute references with pointers, which can be re-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

`bar` is a reference to `boo`, and `boo` is of type `base` whatever you assign to it.

Assignment can only change a variables value, not its type.

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism does not work with references. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class base
{
public:
   virtual void print(){ std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
};
class derived : public base
{
public:
   virtual void print(){ std::cout << "derived" << std::endl; }
};

class derived2 : public base
{
   virtual void print(){ std::cout << "derived2" << std::endl; }
};

class foo
{
public:
   base* bar; 
   foo(): bar(0) {}
   void newfoo(base* newfoo){ bar = newfoo; bar->print(); }
};

int main() {
   foo test;
   test.newfoo(new derived2);
}
```

Comment: _"Polymorphism does not work with references."_ It does, actually. What did you mean? There's the no reference in the example. _(I know it was ~7 years ago, but we are performing here for all eternity. :) )_